# python data construction with multiple values for single item

Tags: python, list, set

I'm not really sure the best way to accomplish this.

```
for line in lines:
    value1 = a
    value2 = b
    value3 = c
```

There are multiple strings that are equal to value2 and value3. So my initial thought was to create a dictionary but the keys initial value was written over with each new value.

How can I get a data structure that looks like:

```
{value1, value2 = [a,b,c], value3 = [d,e,f]}
```

Can I make a list inside a set?

Comment: you  can make a dictionary for it: { 'value1':[ a,b,c], 'value2':[a,b,c], 'value3':[d,e,f]}

Comment: I'm not sure how the requested structure relates to the loop, but from what I understand of your question, it's perfectly possible to store a list of items against a single key in a dictionary e.g. `{value1: [a, b, c], value2: [d, e, f]}`. You could initialise the dictionary with just keys and empty lists associated with those keys, then append to that list, or use something like a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: { 'value1':[ a,b,c], 'value2':[a,b,c], 'value3':[d,e,f]} is on fact the structure I'm looking to create.

defaultdict instructions are about as clear as mud. in the statements. What are "k" and "v" representing?

Comment: @Rthomas529 :) It seems more complicated than it is. First though, are you manually assigning `a`, `b`, `c` etc. against the keys (in other words, writing the dictionary out by hand in the code) or are you trying to _construct_ the dictionary in the code, in which you store `a`, `b`, `c` against the keys as you go around the loop? If the former, there's no need for anything like a defaultdict at all. Aside: `k` and `v` are standard shorthand for "key" and "value".

Comment: I'm attempting to store the values against the keys as it goes through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this purpose. You can then easily create a list against the key, and store the multiple values associated with that key in a list (to avoid your overwrite issue).

On a base level, when you define `my_dict = defaultdict(list)`, what you're saying is that "when I create a new key for this dictionary, automatically assign an empty list to that key as the default value." You can then immediately append your value to the empty list stored against that key. If the key already exists, then it behaves the same way as a regular dictionary.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

choice_of_numbers = range(20) # We will pick randomly from the list and assign to dict keys

my_dict = defaultdict(list) # Create a defaultdict

for x in range(5): # To emulate your for line in lines loop
    my_dict['value1'].append(random.choice(choice_of_numbers))  
    my_dict['value2'].append(random.choice(choice_of_numbers))
    my_dict['value3'].append(random.choice(choice_of_numbers))

print(dict(my_dict)) # We call dict here just to make the appearance more familiar
```